How to prompt for multiple exclusive groups of arguments from python command line
So I'm trying to parse the command line for 2 groups of mutually exclusive arguments.

The user can specify a file
The user can specify a server
along with a view

I'm looking at the argparse.add_mutually_exclusive_group function.  However, it doesn't seem like it will do what I need.  I want to let someone specify a file or specify a jenkins server with a view.  I don't know how to manipulate add_mutually_exclusive_group to either accept a 1 argument group or a 2 argument group.  I will save everyone the pain of looking at my other failed trials but I'm getting the feeling either

I'm using add_mutually_exclusive_group wrong or
I'm using the wrong function to accomplish what I want.

Here's my code, although, I know it's wrong because I'm not using it correctly to make jenkins and view be a group but I don't know what to do to accomplish that.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--file', dest='file', help='Get jobs from file') 
group.add_argument('--jenkins', dest='jenkins', help='Get jobs from Jenkins view and separate by section')
group.add_argument('--view', dest='view')


mutually_exclusive is a simple flat 'xor'.  You can't create subgroups within it (either 'or' or 'and').  It isn't a general purpose grouping tool.  The best you do is a nargs to accept multiple values for one of the arguments.

Your code is very close to what it needs to be, you're specification for mutually exclusive should look more like this, and also have a catch to require --view only when using --jenkins:
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('--file', dest='file')
group.add_argument('--jenkins', dest='jenkins')
parser.add_argument('--view', dest='view')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.jenkins and not args.view:
  parser.error("--view is required when using --jenkins")

EDIT: After posting I noticed a slightly cleaner (but not necessarily better) way to do this after looking at the docs, but it would require you to process the command slightly differently:
group.add_argument('--jenkins', dest='jenkins', nargs=2, metavar=('JENKINS', 'VIEW'))

This will send the array ['ABC', 'XYZ'] to the jenkins destination
metavar changes how the name is displayed in help, so it'll show:
usage: test_parse.py [-h] (--file FILE | --jenkins JENKINS VIEW)
test_parse.py: error: argument --jenkins: expected 2 arguments

nargs=2 implies that the argument must be used twice, requiring the user to input --jenkins ABC XYZ instead of --jenkins ABC --view XYZ
